# Visio Database Design - Unsure of additional Foreign Keys added by Visio

Tags: sql, database-design, database-schema

Please see the following example Database Model i made to help visualize my problem:

[image]

In this example, the relationship between `car and history is 1 to zero or more` and relationship between `car and options is 1 to zero or more`.

both tables have  `car car_id` as foreign key but Visio also wants `customer`  table primary key for each of these tables as foreign key as seen in the diagram above. I am not sure if that's necessary/correct. if i remove the added foreign keys , visio marks the relationship as non-identifiable (dotted line) so i feel as though i am doing something wrong

would anyone be able to tell me why Visio is adding the `customer cust_id` to child tables of `car`? and whether or not removing the Foreign Keys manually is bad idea in this case?

### Updated Diagram based on comments (and selected answer)

[image]

Comment: Visio is adding `cust_id` because it's part of the `car` table's PK: `(cust_id, car_id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing "wrong" with non-identifying relationship per-se.

Is `car_id` unique **on its own**, or in the context of `cust_id` (so we can have same `car_id` for different `cust_id`s)?

- If it's unique on its own, the `customer`-`car` relationship should be non-identifying.
- Otherwise it should be identifying. A natural consequence of this is the propagation of `cust_id` to all "downstream" entities.

BTW, the same question could be asked about `opt_id` and `hist_id` - are they unique on their own or in the context of the `car`'s PK? The answer determines whether `car`-`options` and `car`-`history` relationships should be identifying or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please correct me if i am wrong but in above example the `relationship between CAR and CUSTOMER` should be `non-identifiable` given either can exists independently. I made the change in the Diagram (See updated question) and effects are seen in "Downstream" tables as well.

Comment: @techventure This is not a matter of whether `car` can exist independently (it cannot, since you have a non-NULL FK to another table), but whether it can be _identified_ independently. Assuming it can, your new diagram looks OK. Of course, the same question can be asked for all other relationships (e.g. can `invoice` be identified with the `in_id` **alone**, etc...).